# Combining Rows from Different Tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 2 tables. 1 table have 3 rows and another table have 5 rows. I wanted to join this both tables together and the result should show 3rows and 5 rows respectively. Is there any ways that could achieve that using sql statement? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's not joining, that's obtaining a union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION` for this,

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, 1 as OrderThis
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT colA, colB, colC, 2 as OrderThis
FROM tableB
ORDER BY OrderThis ASC
```

There are two basic rules of using `UNION`

- the number of columns must be the same from both queries
- the data types must be compatible

`UNION` has an optional parameter `ALL`. if you omit `ALL` parameter, `UNION` will distinctly display all unique records that were combined.

As you can see, I have added a *virtual column* `OrderThis`. This will be the basis for the ordering of your rows. But the Problem is it will show on your result list. the solution is by wrapping it in a subquery,

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC
FROM
(
    SELECT colA, colB, colC, 1 as OrderThis
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT colA, colB, colC, 2 as OrderThis
    FROM tableB
) a
ORDER BY OrderThis ASC
```

Comment: is it rows or columns must be same.